# Java ProcessBuilder construction

Tags: java, jar, processbuilder

I am trying to start an external program within my Java application.

This is how I start the program from command line:

> java -cp tests\presenter.jar;debug\viewer.jar libs.at.PresenterTool
>   --mode=sync  --width=1024 --height=768

I tried other examples posted but couldn't make it work.

```
List<String> argList = new ArrayList<>();

argList.add("java");
argList.add("-cp");
argList.add("tests\presenter.jar;debug\viewer.jar");
argList.add("libs.at.PresenterTool");
argList.add("--mode=sync");
argList.add("--width=1024");
argList.add("--height=768");

ProcessBuilder pBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(argList);
Process p = pBuilder.start();
```

And once I am able to start the program, I'm hoping to kill that process by using `p.destroy()`.

Comment: Remember to double the backslashes when in a Java string literal: `"tests\\presenter.jar;debug\\viewer.jar"`

Comment: Did you read the process `InputStream` and error streams?  What did `Process#exitValue` return after the process terminated?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Good point. OP should probably call `pBuilder.inheritIO()` before calling `start()`, if not otherwise processing output, though it looks to be a GUI program, so there might not be any output.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I haven't done Java GUI, but would using `javaw` be better/required?

Comment: Nothing happens when I execute that line. I don't even get an exception. I'll look into InputStreams..

Comment: @Andreas `javaw` just doesn't create a console window, so it depends on your requirements

Comment: This opens a window which shows a jpeg. It doesn't have any console output. I just need that window to stay open. It works fine if I start it from the command line. Is the order of the array items correct ?

Comment: You need the window to stay open. What is it doing right now?

Comment: Nothing. pBuilder.start() doesn't start the program.